# How do I sync the geospatial data from kafka topic to postgres?

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, postgis, apache-kafka-connect, ksqldb

I have been trying to sync the geospatial data from kafka topic to postgres db with postgis enabled. So the geospatial data is in form of array [lat, lng] at the moment in kafka topic. I want to sync this field as (Point(lat,lng), SRID) in postgres in `location` column instead of two different columns of `lat` and `lng`. I am using jdbcConnector and KSQL server at the moment.

Is it possible to sync geospatial data from kafka topic to postres? What options are there to sync geospatial data to postgres?

I looked into Single Message Transform but that didn't do the trick. I also found [Geomesa](https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/tutorials/geomesa-quickstart-kafka.html) which looks like it does the thing but I want to use Postgres.

How could I solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey mate, have you got any solution to this? I am facing the same problem as yours now.

Comment: Sorry mate. The project didn't move forward and I never bothered to look for solution. I hope you find the solution to it.